# Hide table cell content without ruining spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a table, and I want to make it so that it is initially collapsed, but clicking on a side heading expands the relevant section. (Explanations aren't my forte, [but I have a fiddle here that does almost what I want](http://jsfiddle.net/StephenTG/HWbDA/))

The main issue now is that the subheadings still show up when highlighted, which isn't what I want. I've tried collapsing the `<th>`'s, but that leaves an ugly white gap, even when I try giving the first `<th>` a large enough `colspan`.

Here's the relevant code (pulled straight from [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StephenTG/HWbDA/)):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th colspan=4>Heading</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="type-header" rowspan=3>Type 1</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Name</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Content</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Data</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none">
                    <td>Some Name</td>
                    <td>Some Content</td>
                    <td>Some Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none">
                    <td>Another Name</td>
                    <td>More Content</td>
                    <td>More Data</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="type-header" rowspan=3>Type 2</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Name</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Content</th>
                    <th class="invisible-cell">Data</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none">
                    <td>Some Name</td>
                    <td>Some Content</td>
                    <td>Some Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none">
                    <td>Another Name</td>
                    <td>More Content</td>
                    <td>More Data</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.type-header').click(function () {
$(this).parent().nextUntil('type-header').toggle();
$(this).siblings().toggleClass("invisible-cell");
});
```

CSS:

```
.table th.invisible-cell {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there a way I can hide the text even from highlighting (without screwing up the spacing)? Basically, I want the text to remain there as a placeholder, but be undetectable (short of examining the html itself or something, that's fine)

Comment: I don't see any text being highlighted // using chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `visibility:hidden` and wrap the `th` content in a span, so you do not make it totally invisible, just the content.

Example:

```
<th><span>The element with the hidden visibility</span></th>
```

Since you are hidding only the content, you can use (also) display:none. That way it wont show up anything.

Comment: The td stuff is fine. It's the th stuff (Name, Content, Data) that I want more hidden

Comment: Sorry, it was the th elements.

Comment: Ok, moving the `invisible-cell` class into a span seems to be working. Just need to make the borders go away again, should be able to figure that out

Comment: Got the borders gone. There's still something showing up when it's highlighted, but it's quite a bit better. Plus, the cursor doesn't transform into the I-shape that suggests there's something to highlight, and they won't show up with Ctrl-F and the like

Comment: Now that you are hidding only the content, you can use display:none instead of visibility:hidden. That way it wont show up anything.

Comment: Excellent. Edit that into the answer and I'll accept

Comment: you could have used text-indent and even width:auto to even shrink your table : http://jsfiddle.net/HWbDA/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus I didn't want it shrunk

Comment: then , just text-indent, no span needed :) http://jsfiddle.net/HWbDA/2/ (text-indent doesn't hide content to screen readers nor bots ,)

Answer (score 2):

text-indent works too in your case :

```
.table th.invisible-cell {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWbDA/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.table th.invisible-cell {
    font-size:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set the css property `visibility: hidden;` instead of using display none.

possibly:

```
.table th.invisible-cell {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That just leaves an ugly white gap, as mentioned before

Comment: That's what I had to start. It's almost right, but if you select a row while it's collapsed you can still see the headings

Answer (score 0):

Remove your ugly white gap when making the row invisible by removing cellpadding, spacing and border.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

Also make sure margins and padding for the page are set to 0.  This should do the trick.